# JavaScript - How to increment a counter to data in records

Tags: javascript, arrays, counter, increment

How would I increment a counter so that it counts the number of students in a certain ZIP code?

The data that I have is:

```
101 Student 1   123 Some St.    53712   M   S   FT  20  18520
102 Student 2   2205 Grand St.  53712   M   F       20  18500
103 Student 3   190 Fox St.     53713   F   S   PT  25  18530
```

The code that I currently have is:

```
output = document.getElementById('outputDiv');

while (studentRecords.readNextRecord()) {

    currentNumber        =  studentRecords.getStudentNumber();
    currentName          =  studentRecords.getStudentName();
    currentAddress       =  studentRecords.getStudentAddress();
    currentZipCode       =  studentRecords.getStudentZipCode();
    currentGender        =  studentRecords.getStudentGender();
    currentCourseNumber  =  studentRecords.getStudentCourseNumber();
    zipArray.push(currentZipCode);

    zipArray.sort();

    for(var i = 0; i < zipArray.length; i++) {
        if(zipArray[i] != zipArray[i+1]) {
            display += "<br>" + zipArray[i]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any javascript code at all as a starting point?

Comment: What solutions have you tried?

Comment: You write a for loop, and set separate counters for each zip code you wish to count an instance of.

Comment: Use an object whose keys are the zip codes, and values are the count.

Comment: give structure of "studentRecords"

Answer (score 0):

Create your counter variables. Load the addresses (if from a database) into an array (addresses). Then do your if statements here to compare whether the address you are searching for (addressSearchingFor) is the address at position x in the array, then increment the correct counter (area1Count).

```
 var area1Count = 0;
 var area2Count = 0;
 var area3Count = 0;

  var addresses = [...]
  for (var x = 0; x <= addresses.length; x++{
      if(addresses[x] == addressSearchingFor){
          area1Count+=1;
      }
  }
```

But your question is quite vague, but work on what I've written and develop it more. But keep the basic idea of looping through all addresses and comparing them and then increasing a counter.